# How to disable sortable animation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable the sorting animation?
I find it annoying when I drop items in the end that there's an animation.

Try dragging items into the box and see the effect. You should have at least one item and you should drop the item second last or last position.

```
 plnkr.co/edit/Jw1S9ij7jbyaeEcO8UEl?p=preview[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `revertDuration` option in your draggable configuration.

```
$(".draggable li").draggable({
     //..
     revertDuration: 0
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FxkTYanq1S4nHIbhNT21?p=preview